# Passing parameters as parameters in templates in JSF 2.0

Tags: templates, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I'm having difficulty finding support on this topic, because I know how to pass parameters to a template.  What I want to do is pass parameters to not be used as parameters to the template but to a component within the template.

For example, in primefaces, you can write the following logic to create a button:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{printBean.print}">
  <f:attribute name="report" value="report.jrxml" />
</p:commandButton>
```

This is all fine and good when I don't need to pass parameters.  However, I need to construct a template which allows me to specify parameters to pass to the report dynamically.  My first attempt was to do the following:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{printBean.print}">
  <f:attribute name="report" value="report.jrxml" />
  <ui:insert name="reportParams" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Which would allow me to use the template in the following manner:

```
<ui:decorate template="templates/report.xhtml" >
  <ui:define name="reportParams>
    <f:attribute name="reportParam1" value="paramVal1" />
    <f:attribute name="reportParam2" value="paramVal2" />
    <f:attribute name="reportParam3" value="paramVal3" />        
    ...
  </ui:define>
</ui:decorate>
```

However parameters passed in this way are not received in my action listener in printBean, yet parameter "report" is.  I think the attributes passed in this way are interpreted to mean that it is referring to the ui:define tag, and not to be inserted in the template as I would want.

Is there an alternative way of achieving the same way?  Keep in mind I'm using JSF 2.0 and primefaces, but not Seam or any added libraries and ideally I would not have to add any libraries to make it work.

I apologize if an answer to this question already exists, but it's maddening searching for an answer to this question.

**EDIT**: The number of parameters is variable, meaning I can't simply use ui:param and put the value of that parameter as an attribute value within the template, because there could be many such parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [composite component](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info) instead of a template.

Create this file `/resources/mycomponents/printReport.xhtml`:

```html
<ui:component
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
>
    <cc:interface>
        <!-- No attributes. -->
    </cc:interface>
    <cc:implementation>
        ...
        <p:commandButton value="Print" action="#{printBean.print}" />
        ...
    </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

Use it as follows:

```html
xmlns:my="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/mycomponents"
...
<my:printReport>
    <f:attribute name="reportParam1" value="paramVal1" />
    <f:attribute name="reportParam2" value="paramVal2" />
    <f:attribute name="reportParam3" value="paramVal3" />
</my:printReport>
```

Rewrite the `print` method as follows:

```java
public void print() {
    UIComponent composite = UIComponent.getCurrentCompositeComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    String reportParam1 = (String) composite.getAttributes().get("reportParam1");
    String reportParam2 = (String) composite.getAttributes().get("reportParam2");
    String reportParam3 = (String) composite.getAttributes().get("reportParam3");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can I cycle through all attributes this way?  `for(String attr : composite.getAttributes().keySet()) { ... }`??

Comment: Not if those attributes are value expessions instead of plain vanila strings. You could alternatively iterate over it as follows: `for (int i = 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) { Object value = composite.getAttributes().get("reportParam" + i); if (value == null) break; }`.

Comment: True, but I was really hoping to do something like pass "reportParam.id", "reportParam.plantId", "reportParam.locationCode" and be able to find all starting with "reportParam." and insert it as a parameter to my jasper report.  Though, maybe you can't have it all.

Comment: You could pass them commaseparated as another attribute with fixed name like so `<f:attribute name="properties" value="id,plantId,locationCode" />` and then use it to obtain the real attributes.

Comment: True, still not quite what I was hoping for.  I would have thought they'd find a way to fix all these issues in 2.0, but I guess a few still remain.  Thank you for your help, BalusC.